# Unicorn: Start, Stop and Restart Centos 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

I've just setup nginx and unicorn. I start unicorn like this:

```
unicorn_rails -c /var/www/Web/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

I've tried the various commands for stopping the unicorn but none of them work. I usually just restart the server and start unicorn again but this is very annoying.

EDIT

unicorn.rb file (/var/www/Web/config/):

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/var/www/Web"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/var/www/Web/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/var/www/Web/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/www/Web/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
listen "/tmp/unicorn.Web.sock"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.Web.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

default.conf (/etc/nginx/conf.d/):

```
upstream app {
# Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.Web.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {


listen 80;
server_name localhost;

# Application root, as defined previously
root /root/Web/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: /etc/init.d/unicorn_Xxx reload

Comment: I get this result: /etc/init.d/unicorn_Web: No such file or directory

Comment: You should replace unicorn_xxx with your unicorn file did u used capistrano?  If yes put the path to unicorn with reload/stop/start

Comment: I didn't deploy with capistrano but I've included more info in the question

Comment: Paste your unicorn sh file also

Comment: I'm not sure where that's found

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5

Comment: I used that to set it up but it doesn't say anything about stopping a unicorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
$ for i in `ps awx | grep unico | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1;}'`; do kill -9 $i; done && unicorn_rails  -c /var/www/Web/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

If you don't want to have all this line, script it, like this:

/var/www/Web/unicorn_restart.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ps awx | grep unicorn | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1;}'`; do 
    kill $i 
done
unicorn_rails  -c /var/www/Web/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

and then:

```
$ chmod +x /var/www/Web/unicorn_restart.sh
```

summon it each time calling:

$ /var/www/Web/unicorn_restart.sh